# ¿Campos "Nombre" y "Apellidos" y "Apellidos, Nombre" en una tabla en SQL?

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo SQL. Me encuentro en la siguiente situación: Tengo varios csv (cientos de miles de lineas) con datos, entre ellos, nombre y apellidos de personas. En algunos sitios están en un campo el nombre, y en otros el apellido. En otros está en el mismo campo el nombre y los apellidos. Y en otros casos, está en un campo los Apellidos, Nombre.

Esto no me supone un problema, porque con excel me manejo, y puedo ir trabajando. Pero la cuestión es que quiero saber la mejor forma de hacer en sql.

He hecho la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nombres VARCHAR(255),
apellidos VARCHAR(255),
apellidos_nombre VARCHAR(255));
```

La cuestión es que quiero hacerlo bien desde el principio, pero no sé cuál es la mejor forma. La idea, en un futuro, es crear una web y subir estos datos a una tabla para temas de estadística, y no me importaría (de hecho, lo preferiría), que en algunos sitios apareciera todo junto en un campo, en otros separado, y en otros Apellidos, nombre. Es decir, mezclado.

También le he preguntado a chatGPT y me dice esto:

```
-- Crear la tabla con un campo autoincrementable para ID
CREATE TABLE TuTabla (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50),
    Apellidos VARCHAR(50),
    NombreApellidosConcatenados VARCHAR(100), -- Este campo almacenará "nombre apellidos"
    ApellidosNombreInvertido VARCHAR(100) -- Este campo almacenará "apellidos, nombre"
);

-- Para que los campos 'NombreApellidosConcatenados' y 'ApellidosNombreInvertido' se actualicen automáticamente, puedes usar triggers en MySQL. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo crear un trigger para el campo 'NombreApellidosConcatenados':
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_NombreApellidosConcatenados
BEFORE INSERT ON TuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.NombreApellidosConcatenados = CONCAT(NEW.Nombre, ' ', NEW.Apellidos);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

-- Y aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo crear un trigger para el campo 'ApellidosNombreInvertido':
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ApellidosNombreInvertido
BEFORE INSERT ON TuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.ApellidosNombreInvertido = CONCAT(NEW.Apellidos, ', ', NEW.Nombre);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Insisto, el objetivo final es crear una web con unas tablas. Me gustaría que en unas tablas apareciera de una forma, y en otras tablas, de otra. Pienso que creando ahora una tabla "Nombre y Apellidos", con varios campos distribuidos de la forma que he comentado anteriormente, es una buena forma. Y colocarle un ID delante para distinguirlo. Pero no sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Buenas, Eltruji, pues se ha lucido bien chatGPT. Podemos estar tranquilos, todavía no nos va a quitar el trabajo. En principio no se recomienda almacenar campos calculados, cuyos valores pueden determinarse fácilmente a partir de otros campos ya presentes en la tabla. Es decir, yo almacenaría nombre, apellido1 y apellido2. Puedes obtener cualquier concatenación que quieras de esos campos al ejecutar una consulta sobre esa tabla.

Comment: Además la idea de una base de datos relacional es que no tengas que replicar la info en todas las tablas; es decir, en tu tabla de estadísticas no hace falta que tengas el nombre y los apellidos sino solo una clave externa que referencie el registro en la tabla usuarios al que se refiere ese apunte estadístico.

Comment: Coincido con el colega de arriba. Guarda los campos separados, de esta manera cuando necesites presentarlos puedes hacerlo fácilmente en el formato que quieras

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos. Entonces, me recomendáis almacenar los apellidos por separado. Perfecto, no es ningún problema. Ahora bien, ¿Me recomendáis separarlos en el excel y despues subirlos a la BBDD? Por otro lado, teniendo en cuenta que tengo nombres indios, por ejemplo, que tienen bastantes "apellidos" ¿Cómo lo haríais?

Comment: Hombre, lo suyo es "prepararlos" antes de insertar. Con lo de los nombres indios no puedo ayudarte. ¿Cómo aparecen esos apellidos en el documento de identificación de su pais? Justamente he pensado en ese problema pero con los dos apellidos que usamos los hispanohablantes. A nosotros suelen almacenarnos el primer apellido en su campo nombre.